# Problems by Toggle Button

Tags: android, service, togglebutton

My toggleButton are not working properly, what can i do??
If i press toggleButton1 then ultimately toggelButton2 got pressed,as it is not getting the code of toggelButton1.
But toggelButton2 is working perfectly
Please any one can help me, in fixing my Problem

```
ToggleButton toggle1, toggle2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_act);

     toggle1= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
     toggle2= (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);

       SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences(null, 0);
        if(spref.getBoolean("one", false)) {
            toggle1.setChecked(true);
            toggle2.setEnabled(false);    
        } else if(spref.getBoolean("two", false)) {
            toggle2.setChecked(true);
            toggle1.setEnabled(false);    
        }

        toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {

              toggle2.setEnabled(!isChecked);
              getSharedPreferences(null, 0).edit()
              .putBoolean("one", isChecked)
              .apply();
           startService(new           Intent(MainActActivity.this,LockScreenService.class));
            }
        });
             toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(newCompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               toggle1.setEnabled(!isChecked);
               getSharedPreferences(null, 0).edit()
                   .putBoolean("two", isChecked)
                   .apply();
startService(new Intent(MainActActivity.this,PinLockService.class)); }}); }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences(mContext, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(spref.getBoolean("one", false)) {
        toggle1.setChecked(true);
        toggle2.setChecked(false);    
    } else if(spref.getBoolean("two", false)) {
        toggle2.setChecked(true);
        toggle1.setChecked(false);    
    }

    toggle1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
if(isChecked){
spref.edit()
          .putBoolean("one", isChecked).commit();

       startService(new           Intent(MainActActivity.this,LockScreenService.class));
        }
}
    });
         toggle2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(newCompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if(isChecked){
spref.edit()
          .putBoolean("two", isChecked).commit();

       startService(new           Intent(MainActActivity.this,PinLockService.class));
        }
}
    }}); }}
```

Comment: Have you set default selection to toggle buttons in your xml??

Comment: yes i did, the problem is actually when i press toggelbutton1, the code under the toggelbutton2 appered to be set on lockscreen, hence it should be of toggelbutton1 ..... but for toggelbutton2 code is working perfectly.

Comment: Try witth 

 toggle1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (toggle1.isChecked()){
                    
            }
        });

Comment: Dont use enable or anything else And don't set default checked from your xml 
clean  project and run

Comment: actually what i have to do is, i have two togglebuttons one for pattern(togglebutton1) and other for pin(togglebutton2), when i select pattern to be selected on my lockscreen the the pin should be disabled, and vice verse.... so for that reason i have to use enable and the stuff like that.

Comment: i did so, still it behaving like what i dont want.

Comment: Can i send you my code so that you may got to know what i am asking for.

Comment: Mail is sent to you @Nilay